# Django its not printing on HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to understand why Django its not printing on my HTML page, the user db its printing just fine but my ticket db its not being printed, it actually creates the space to allocate the information, as its shown on the image, but it doesn't fill the information on it.

**views.py**

```python
#The actual page
def dashboard(request):
    ticket = Userdb.objects.filter(userid = request.user.id)
    context = {'ticket': ticket}
    return render(request,'dashboard/home.html', context)

#Data in the ticket
def ticketr(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('nomctt') and request.POST.get('tiposerv') and request.POST.get('areaserv') and request.POST.get('tickettext'):
            table = Userdb()
            table.nomctt = request.POST.get('nomctt')
            table.numctt = request.POST.get('numctt')
            table.tiposerv = request.POST.get('tiposerv')
            table.areaserv = request.POST.get('areaserv')
            table.tickettext = request.POST.get('tickettext')
            table.userid = request.user
            table.save()
            data['msg'] = 'Ticket registrado!'
            data['class'] = 'alert-success'    
            return render(request,'dashboard/home.html', data)
        else:
         data['msg'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
         data['class'] = 'alert-danger'
        return render(request,'dashboard/ticket.html',data)
```

**home.html**

```html
{% block content %}
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" style="width:180px;height:100px;"></a>
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
            <ul class="navbar__menu">
              
            <li class="navbar__item">
                <a href="/" class="navbar__links">
                    {{ user.username }}
                </a>
            </li>
            
            <li class="navbar__btn">
                <a href="/loginv" class="button">
                    Logar
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


    <a href="/dashboard/ticket/">Abra um Ticket</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container bootdey">  
        <div class="col-md-12">  
            <div class="col-md-4">      
                <div class="portlet light profile-sidebar-portlet bordered">
                    <div class="profile-usertitle">
                        <div class="profile-usertitle-name"> {{ user.username }} </div>
                        <div class="profile-usertitle-job"> Developer </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="profile-usermenu">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="icon-home"></i> Ticket List </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="icon-info"></i> Configurations </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8"> 
                <div class="portlet light bordered">
                    <div class="portlet-title tabbable-line">
                        <div class="caption caption-md">
                            <i class="icon-globe theme-font hide"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject font-blue-madison bold uppercase">Ticket List</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Column heading</th>
                                    <th>Column heading</th>
                                    <th>Column heading</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for Userdb in ticket %}
                                <tr class="active">
                                    <th scope="row">{{ticket.ticketid}}</th>
                                    <td>{{ticket.nomctt}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ticket.numctt}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ticket.tickettext}}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                               
    {% else %}
        Você não tem acesso a essa área!
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Actual page

[image: Page rendered]

If any more information is needed please just comment it and i shall provide it

Comment: `{% for Userdb in ticket %}` Where is the `ticket` variable defined?

Comment: Here? 


`def dashboard(request):
    ticket = Userdb.objects.filter(userid = request.user.id)
    context = {'ticket': ticket}
    return render(request,'dashboard/home.html', context)`

Comment: Oh, I was looking at the second view function.  I overlooked the first one.

Comment: But I think the problem is still with the `{{ticket}}` variable.  As passed from the view code, the `ticket` variable is the results of `.filter()` so it is actually a _list_ of tickets. The `ticket` variable itself does not have a `.ticketid` attribute etc.

Comment: So, I changed `{{ ticket.ticketid }}` to `{{ Userdb.ticketid }}` and it worked, but I cant help but feel like its gonna cause problems, I don't think it has to do with it, but after some other changes when I create a ticket it gets saved 3 times in the database, im really lost rn xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view function, I would rename the `ticket` variable to `tickets` (plural), so it's more obvious that it's actually a *list* of tickets.  Having variable names that actually match the expected content is really helpful:

```
def dashboard(request):
    tickets = Userdb.objects.filter(userid = request.user.id)
    context = {'tickets': tickets}
    return render(request,'dashboard/home.html', context)
```

But the real problem is that the html template assumes `ticket` is each separate ticket, not the list itself:

```
{% for Userdb in ticket %}
<tr class="active">
    <th scope="row">{{ticket.ticketid}}</th>
    <td>{{ticket.nomctt}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.numctt}}</td>
    <td>{{ticket.tickettext}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming that you made my recommended change above, you can change just the `for` loop tag to this:

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
```

Or if you don't want to make that change, you can change `{{ticket.ticketid}}` to `{{Userdb.ticketid}}` and all of the other similar variables.

Comment: Just did that and it works just fine, I didn't know that I could just do `{% for ticket in tickets %}` , I guess it creates the `ticket` variable on the go? Anyways, thank you for the help and sorry to take your time

Comment: @Yukki Yes a `for item in mylist` loop automatically creates the `item` variable.